# Data Binding RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I'm trying to enable continous scrolling on android using RecyclerView however I'm encountering and error "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first" when using a fragment. When I run the same code on an activity it works perfectly. Below is my code:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    private HashMap loc = new HashMap();
    private ArrayList<String> orderNumber = new ArrayList<>(),
            items = new ArrayList<>(), location = new ArrayList<>();
    private RelativeLayout fragmentContainer;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private List<String> mStringList;
    private int mLoadedItems = 0;
    private SampleAdapter mSampleAdapter;
    private MainActivityBinding mActivityMainBinding;

    public static TestFragment newInstance() {
        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(getActivity(), R.layout.main_activity);
        View view = mActivityMainBinding.getRoot();
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mActivityMainBinding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mActivityMainBinding.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        mStringList = new ArrayList<>();
        mSampleAdapter = new SampleAdapter(mStringList);
        mActivityMainBinding.recyclerView.setAdapter(mSampleAdapter);
        addDataToList();

        mActivityMainBinding.recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);

        return view;

    }

    private final RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int newState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {

            addDataToList();
        }
    };
    private void addDataToList() {
        mActivityMainBinding.itemProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
                    mStringList.add("SampleText : " + mLoadedItems);
                    mLoadedItems++;
                }
                mSampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mActivityMainBinding.itemProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 1500);

    }

}
```

Comment: you mean to say if you comment out `addDataToList();` it works fine?

Comment: Which is the error line?